# How to view the IP of the connecting client in Domino 9 IMAP server?

Tags: ip-address, imap, ibm-domino

I am running an IBM Domino 9.0.1 (64-bit) server on a Windows Server 2008 R2.

The problem is that the **IMAP** server task is not displaying the IP address of the connecting client in the console and log.

Here's an example from the console log:

`2016-01-08 04:13:14   nimap: edd [] authentication failure using internet password
2016-01-08 04:13:16   nimap: easter [] authentication failure using internet password
2016-01-08 04:13:19   nimap: felicity [] authentication failure using internet password`

Between the brackets `[]` there should be the IP address. For some reason it is not being output.

In contrast, the **SMTP** server task displays the IP of the connecting client properly, so I don't expect it to be a DNS or similar network configuration issue.

---

In order to get more details, I've created an event monitor tied to this event, which runs an agent that saves the details of the event in a document.
[Here is one such document (displayed as a table of field names/values)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkGwf.png).
As you see, it doesn't contain any useful info about the client's IP.

---

So, how can I get to know the IP of the connecting client without resolving to TCP monitoring tools?

TIA

---

P.s.: I'm aware that this is a dictionary attack.

Comment: Is it only me, or can anyone confirm that they can see the IMAP client's IP in the server log/console?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to perform that with the "IMAP activity logging" as written [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_8.0.1/com.ibm.help.domino.admin.doc/DOC/H_IMAP_ACTIVITY_LOGGING_OVER.html). The documentation clearly said:

> "IMAP activity logging tracks IMAP session activity, such as the user
>   name, the server name, **the IP address of the client**, the number of
>   bytes the client sent to and read from the server, and the duration of
>   the session."

Which should be what you are looking for.

Comment: From what I understand, this only works for authenticated clients.

My issue is that I want to identify the IPs causing failing login attempts.

Comment: I'll try the "Close records" option and see what it information it can provide....